# Writing second power of numerator in PlotLabel

Tags: plotting, text

I want to label my plot. I have done  some part of it till now:

```
a22 = Plot[{3 x}, {x, 0, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(C\)]< \* \FractionBox[SubscriptBox[ \(f +b\), \(m\)], \(yu\)]\)"}, Exclusions -> 3/(x - 1) == 0, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], {Orange, Dashing[None]}}, Ticks -> None]
```

But I want to write second power of numerator in the output. Does anyone know how can I change numerator with second power of it?

Comment: Can you write down expression that you want to put in plot legend?

Comment: -(-x+a y_t)^2/f it is what I need. Is it clear? @ercegovac

Comment: I prefer the fraction be written in with horizontal line instead of /. @ercegovac

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#30487) - you can simply enter the expression the way you want to see it in the legend

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
Plot[{3 x}, {x, 0, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotLegends -> {TraditionalForm[-(-x + a Subscript[y, t])^2/f]}, 
 Exclusions -> 3/(x - 1) == 0, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], {Orange, Dashing[None]}}, 
 Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Mathematica has multiple forms of presenting data. Check [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MathematicalTypesetting.html) tutorial to understand various forms.

Comment: `TraditionalForm` uses a lot of ad-hoc rules and heuristics in attempt to present data in the way traditional to mathematics.